# Firebase Database not showing up when using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use the firebase database but when I try to create a reference with the Firebase Database it does not even have the module. Is there something I'm missing.

[image: There is no FirebaseDatabase]

[image: This is the app delegate]

Comment: Added missing images.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `pod 'FirebaseDatabase', '~> 4.0'` to your `pod` file ?

Also to get a `DatabaseRefrence` you would do so using the following `Database.database().reference()`